# Re-use animation throughout iOS views

Tags: ios, swift, animation, addtarget

Not sure if my thinking here is correct but I have similar animations I use throughout my iOS project and I would like to condense it to 1 file and reuse wherever I want.

A brief example. In my animations file I have a scale animation

**Animations.swift**

```
class Animations {

    class func scaleSmall(_ view: UIView) {
        let scaleAnim = POPBasicAnimation(propertyNamed: kPOPLayerScaleXY)
        scaleAnim?.toValue = NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 0.9, height: 0.9))
        view.layer.pop_add(scaleAnim, forKey: "scaleSmallAnim")
    }

}
```

Here I have one of my many swift files in my View folder and I would like to add that animation to the button

**Button.swift**

```
class Button: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Animations.scaleSmall(_:)), for: .touchDown)
    }

}
```

I thought I would be able to reference the animation from an additional file however everytime I do it this way I get the same error

*Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'scaleSmall' that is not exposed to Objective-C*

Am I referencing this function wrong?

Comment: You are doing it right. Its just that Swift classes are not entirely compatible with Obj-C, and `UIKit` (i.e. `UIButton`) is in Obj-C world. You can try either inheriting from `NSObject` by your `Animations` class or marking your method as `@objc`.

Comment: The confusing thing for me is if I have the animation inside my Button class I can access it with #selector(Button.scaleSmall) and it works correctly. Soon as I bring it out of the file I cant get it correctly

Answer (score 1):

try changing `class func scaleSmall(_ view: UIView) {`

to

```
 @objc class func scaleSmall(view: UIView) {
```

Comment: Trying to keep a clean swift file and not mix up objc if I dont have to

Comment: it is not really mixing objc with swift code, @objc before the function is just a flag for the compiler.

Comment: So it gets rid of my error but the next issue I have is the App failing 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'. Doing some investigating into it now

Comment: That may be due to the fact, that you are passing `self` as a target. This means that the button is actually trying to call the method on `self`. I've actually never tried to use static methods as selectors for buttons. Maybe doing it via a singleton of the `Animation` class would work.

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed my comment, so I'm posting an answer. Methods for UIButton need to be bridged to Obj-C. That's what @Kostas Tsoleridis suggests with his answer as well - it is not mixing two languages in one file, you are just marking the method for the compiler. Other solution would be to inherit from `NSObject` by your `Animations` class.

Now, as your confusion mentioned in a comment - it worked, because your `Button` class inherits from `UIButton` which is both from Obj-C world, and also inherits from `NSObject` down the chain.

To also address the issue mentioned in a comment under @Kostas Tsoleridis answer (and to be honest I should have thought about it before) - you can't pass `self` as a target and use a method from another class (even a static one). To solve this, you can use a singleton instance of your `Animations` class, something like this :

```
class Animations {
    static let sharedInstance = Animations()
    @objc class func scaleSmall(_ view: UIView) {
        // your code
    }
}

let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(Animations.sharedInstance, action: #selector(Animations.scaleSmall(_:)), for: .touchDown)
```

Comment: Im starting see what you guys are saying now